# set class fields based on enum value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, enums, enumerate

```
enum Temp {
  VALUE1(Tempclass::getField1)
  VLAUE2(Tempclass::getField2)
  private final Function<Tempclass, String> type;
}

class Tempclass {
  String field1;
  String field2;
}
```

Using the above code I can get the value of `Tempclass` fields based on `enum` values.
Now how to set the fields of `Tempclass` based on `enum` value ex: if `enum` `VALUE2` is selected, then i need to set the `Tempclass` `field2` to the input value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `BiConsumer<Tempclass, String>` taking an instance of `TempClass` and a `String` and set the appropriate field in the class.

```
VALUE1(Tempclass::getField1, Tempclass::setField1),
VALUE2(Tempclass::getField2, Tempclass::setField2);

private final BiConsumer<Tempclass, String> setter;
```

Get the setter from the enum and pass the values to the `accept` method of the BiConsumer.

```
enumInstance.getSetter().accept(tempClassInstance, "some-value");
```

Comment: It is `<NameOfEnum>.VALUE1.getSetter()`